# How to select rows from last 2 hours in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to select the last 2 hours worth of rows from a Symfony/Doctrine unit. In normal MySQL, this would be done like this:
`SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE`Date`> SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)`

But Doctrine does not support these MySQL keywords like `SUBDATE` and `INTERVAL`. In Doctrine documentation, only alternatives for intervals with days and months are given. But I need hours. How do I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use php `DateTime` object - doctrine will handle this for you

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->modify('-2 hour');

$this
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->andWhere('t.date > :date')
    ->setParameter(':date', $date)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I was stuck in thinking in DQL terms, instead of using the query builder!

Comment: Oh and my query uses a JOIN statement, how is this handled in QueryBuilder? Full query: `SELECT p,h FROM DuocastSnmpBundle:Trap p JOIN p.host h WHERE h.importance > 0 AND p.traptime > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) ORDER BY p.traptime DESC`

Comment: you can do it easily with `join` method - check http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: That function is unclear to me. Where do I specify which class I want to join? It only takes the joining field and the field in the other class, but not what class that is...

Comment: Is this possible with -3 month ?

Comment: Be aware, do not format the date to string (e.g. `$date->format(...)`) when passing value to the query builder, pass the entire DateTime object as mentioned in the answer instead. If you format the date (convert object to string) then timezone data may be lost and you may find yourself in timezone-related issues in case your PHP and MySQL are on different time zones. I am not sure if Doctrine solves all of the issues related to these timezone differences but the cases I have been testing looks ok with the object passed in.

Comment: But `new \DateTime()` is not in sync with the database time, so I can't use it. How to do everything in SQL?